# flatten nested json with json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I have a nested json like this :

```
{  
  "Invalids":[  
  {  
     "Comments":"string",
     "InputRequest":{  
        "LinesInfo":[  
           {  
              "LastPipeLineStateIds":[  
                 0
              ],
              "CropId":0
           }
        ],
        "Crop":"string",
        "Year":"string"
     }
  },
  {  
     "Comments":"string",
     "InputRequest":{  
        "LinesInfo":[  
           {  
              "LastPipeLineStateIds":[  
                 0
              ],
              "CropId":0
           }
        ],
        "name":"string",
        "number":"string"
     }
  }
],
"LinesResponse":{  },
"ErrorInfo":"string"
}
```

I want to get a table of 'name' and 'number, if the 'Invalids' is not empty. I'm doing this:

```
a = json_normalize(data['Invalid'])
```

but the output has prefixes like : 'InputRequest.name', which I don't want. how can I get a clean list of 'name's and 'number's (with 'comments' as the metadata)?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it like so:

```py
nested_json = {  
    "Invalids": [  
        ...
     ]
}

def get_names_and_numbers(json_data):
    """
    Return names and numbers in json_data.
    """
    names_list = []
    numbers_list= []

    Invalids = nested_json['Invalids']
    if Invalids: # *note that Invalids is a list an this referers to its lenght*
        names_list.append(Invalids[1]['InputRequest']['name'])
        numbers_list.append(Invalids[1]['InputRequest']['number'])
        return names_list, numbers_list
    else:
         return None, None

names, numbers = get_names_and_numbers(nested_json)
```